# Formula isn't working when selecting a large amount of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula:

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",1,"cd "&$A$2&"|git submodule add "&components!C1:C100&" "&components!A1:A100&"|git submodule update --init --recursive " &components!A1:A100&"|cd " &components!A1:A100&"|git checkout --recurse-submodules "&components!B1:B100),,"|")
```

To make it simple, the purpose of it is to create commands to automatically add a submodule into my local repository, given a submodule path, commit ID and URL.

For example, given these submodule details (path, commit ID, URL):

[image]

The formula will output the following. Which makes it easy for me to then create a bat file of it and run it:

[image]

But the problem with this formula is that whenever I give it a number of submodules that is large (around 90), it breaks and I get a `#CALC` as output instead.

Any help in tweaking the formula to accommodate a large numbers of submodules is appreciated.

Comment: [TEXTJOIN()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c#:~:text=If%20the%20resulting%20string%20exceeds,error.) has character limitation.

Comment: Might be `Power Query` will be the right tool here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Harun24hr TEXTJOIN has a character limit and joining all the text into 1 large string results in meeting the limits.

You could involve REDUCE to not stack all into a single string, but stack the necessary strings line by line and perform the split after completing the first line, then the next, etc.

```
=LET(a,components!A1:A100,
     b,components!B1:B100,
     c,components!C1:C100,
DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),
     LAMBDA(x,y,
            VSTACK(x,
                   TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",1,"cd "&$A$2&"|git submodule add "&INDEX(c,y)&" "&INDEX(a,y)&"|git submodule update --init --recursive " &INDEX(a,y)&"|cd " &INDEX(a,y)&"|git checkout --recurse-submodules "&INDEX(b,y)),,"|")))),
     1))
```